# Proof of consecutive integers

Tags: number-theory

Do there exist consecutive odd integers $a_1,,, a_k$ and consecutive even integers $b_1,,,b_k$ (where k >= 1) such that $a_1 + \cdots   + a_k = b_1 + \cdots   + b_k$ ?

Comment: Sure: $-1+1=0=-2+0+2$.

Comment: Not with the same length, of course. One of the sums will always be larger, term for term, than the other one.

Comment: Henning is correct, it is k on both sides and it is of the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  both the $a$'s and $b$'s be in increasing order.  Then for all $i, a_i-b_i=a_1-b_1$ and the difference between the sums is $k(a_1-b_1)$ which cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

For the case where there are k odds and evens then let the odds be $o_1,o_2,...o_k$ with $o_1<o_2...<o_k$ and the evens be $e_1,e_2...e_k$ with $e_1<e_2...<e_k$ now let S be the sum of the evens and $o_1=e_1+x$. Then the sum of the odds is $s+xk$.

Answer (score 0):

I tried  to prove it a bit differently,

Let the odd integers be $a_1 =2n+1; a_2 = 2n+3,a_3 = 2n+5\cdots a_k = 2n+2k-1$

Let the even integers be $b_1 = 2m; b_2 = 2m+2,b_3 = 2m+4,\cdots...,b_k = 2m+2(k-1)$

Adding each streams, $S_O = 2kn+1+3+\cdots +2k-1$

$S_E = 2km +2+4+\cdots +2(k-1)$

For Odd, $S_O = 2kn+k+2*\frac {k(k+1)}{2}$ Adding k 1's

For Even, $S_E = 2km + 2*\frac {k*(k-1)}{2}$

Now equating these two,$2kn+k^2+2k = 2km + k^2-k$

$k*(2n-2m+3) = 0$

Either $k = 0$ or $m-n = \frac{3}{2}$

Since m and n are integers $m-n$ is not equal to $\frac {3}{2}$

Thus you prove that there do not exist such consecutive odd and even integers that will hold the equality